# Date to string conversion in mongodb collection using python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have downloaded some tweets from Twitter and uploaded them in mongodb through Python.
All records have a creation date attribute in this format:

```
'created_at': 'Fri Mar 12 04:36:10 +0000 2021',
```

I would like to analyze these tweets by date and hour so I would need to convert this date.
So far, I was able to run this command:

```
pipe = [ { "$addFields": 
          { "create_date": 
           { "$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$created_at"} } 
           } 
          },
      { "$group": 
       {
           "_id": "$create_date", 
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }
       },
        {"$sort": {'count':-1}}, 
        {"$limit":10}
        ]  
         
list(tweets.aggregate(pipeline=pipe))
```

which gives me some aggregated result but I would like to create thre new attributes in my collection: Date, Hour and Minute in order to have more flexibility in the analysis.

I cannot find a way to add these three new columns for all my records, by using Python.
Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance,
Francesca

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I managed this in Mongo directly:

```
db.tweets.find().forEach(
  (tweet) => {
    db.tweets.update(
      {_id: tweet._id},
      {$set: {
        created_at: new Date(tweet.created_at)
      }}
    );
  }
);
```